# why customer name is not included in CFCustomerDetails class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, payment-gateway, cashfree

I am using `cashfree-pg-sdk-nodejs` sdk for cashfree payment gateway integration.

when I checked their source code
[CFCustomerDetails class](https://github.com/cashfree/cashfree-pg-sdk-nodejs/blob/d772936613f61d0a0fa0a3f341f1aa4a87b3e800/src/model/cFCustomerDetails.ts)
doesn't have `customerName` attribute.
[image]

although in their [Web Integration - create order](https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/create-order#customer-details) documentation they have this `customer_name` field
[image]

why is that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our notice.
The customer name has been added to **CFCustomerDetails class** and published in the latest version.